# If $f: M \to N$ is a bijective function between $M$ vector space over $K$ and $N$ can be a vector space and $f$ is a linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $f: M \to N$ be a bijective function where $M$ is a vector space over $K$ and $N$ is just a set. I want to prove we can give $N$ a vector space structure over $K$ and prove $f$ is linear.

Of course proving $N$ happen to be a vector space should be proved first. In order to prove that  we can define a sum operation over $N$ to give $N$ the structure of a abelian group I was thinking of taking $n_{1}, n_{2} \in N$ and since $f$ is bijective there are unique $m_{1}, m_{2} \in M$ such that $f(m_{i})=n_{i}$ for $i=1,2$.

So I define $n_{1} + n_{2} = f (f^{1}(n_{1}) + f^{1}(n_{2}))$ but I cant prove $N$ is an abelian group. Also to define an scalar multiplication I was thinking about $n \ast k= f(f^{-1}(n)k)$ for every $n \in N$ and $k \in K$ but again there are some problems since I can’t guarantee $f$ is linear.

Comment: $f$ is a bijection, so $f^{-1}$ is well defined.  So just apply $f^{-1}$ to every element of $N$ and see that the vector space properties of $M$ apply directly to the $f^{-1}$s of $N$.  That is, $f$ takes vectors to new "labels" in $N$ and $f^{-1}$ takes those "labels" back to their vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine. If $n_1,n_2\in N$, define $n_1+n_2=f\bigl(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)\bigr)$. Besides, let $0_N=f(0)$. Then, if $n_1,n_2,n_3\in N$,\begin{align}(n_1+n_2)+n_3&=f\bigl(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)\bigr)+n_3\\&=f\bigl(f^{-1}\bigl(f\bigl(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)\bigr)\bigr)+f^{-1}(n_3)\bigr)\\&=f\bigl(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)+f^{-1}(n_3)\bigr)\end{align}and, by the same argument,$$n_1+(n_2+n_3)=f\bigl(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)+f^{-1}(n_3)\bigr).$$So, $+$ is associative. Besides, if $n\in N$,\begin{align}m+0_N&=f\bigl(f^{-1}(n)+f^{-1}(0_N)\bigr)\\&=f\bigl(f^{-1}(n)+0\bigr)\\&=f\bigl(f^{-1}(n)\bigr)\\&=n,\end{align}and so $0_N$ is an identity element. And so on. And, yes, if $\lambda$ is a scalar and $n\in N$, you should define$$\lambda n=f\bigl(\lambda f^{-1}(n)\bigr).$$Can you check the remaining properties now?

Comment: Thank you so much! @Jose_Carlos_Santos

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Jose_Carlos_Santos I have come with some doubts regarding the proof. Guess the definition of sum and scalar multiplication is not working.  In $f\bigl(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)\bigr)+n_3=f\bigl(f^{-1}\bigl(f\bigl(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)\bigr)\bigr)+f^{-1}(n_3)\bigr)$ we are using $f$ is linear also scalar multiplications properties are not clear after some hours trying to prove them :/

Comment: *You* may be assuming that $f$ is linear. All I did was to use the definition of sum in $N$ that I provided.

Comment: @Jose_Carlos_Santiago No, is just I dont understand how you in $(n_{1} + n_{2}) +n_{3}$ everything was grouped in some $f$ in the second equality. I get lost from the first to the second equality

Comment: Just really understood your associativity proof!!! Nice!!